# Why can't extract data with xidel?

Tags: xml, bash, xidel

Display content in `books.xml`.

```
cat  books.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>   
   <book category="JAVA">
      <title lang="en">Learn Java in 24 Hours</title>
      <author>Robert</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>32.00</price>
   </book>
   <book category="XML">
      <title lang="en">Learn XPath in 24 hours</title>
      <author>Jay Ban</author>
      <year>2010</year>
      <price>16.50</price>
   </book>   
</books>
```

The xquery string:

```
xstring='''
for $x in doc("books.xml")/books/book
where $x/price>30
return $x/title'''
```

Why can't extract the book title whose price is larger than 30 with xidel?

Both `where $x/price>30` and `where $x/price/text)>30` can't take effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your xml is stored in file.xml, this should work:

`xidel  file.xml --xquery 'for $x in //book where  $x/price/text()  gt 30  return $x/title`'

My output:

```
Learn Java in 24 Hours
```

Comment: It take no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
xquery='''
for $x in doc("books.xml")/books/book
where $x/price/text() >30
return $x/title'''
```

The bash command:

```
xidel books.xml --xquery  "$xquery"
```